# Width in tablelayout in android not going full screen

Tags: android, xml

I have following code but width of the button is not full screen. That is small space is left from both sides of the button which I dont want. I want that whole screen width to be covered horizontally.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#848484"
tools:context="com.example.bepolite.BePolite" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/sign_up"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="80sp"
android:text="Sign Up"  
android:textStyle="bold"  
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="30sp"   
android:background="@drawable/button_signup"
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/Log_in"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="80sp"
android:text="Login"  
android:textStyle="bold"  
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="30sp"    
android:background="@drawable/button_login"
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/whatisbepolite"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="80sp"
android:text="Uderstanding Being Polite???" 
android:textStyle="bold"  
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:background="@drawable/button_whatisbeingpolite"    
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: See my answer for solution and please accept if it works/comment me if it doesn't, good luck with your app. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the padding from the layout. Remove these lines and your view should look fine:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```